# intellij stop autoformatting a blank line around java initializer code that uses braces

Tags: java, syntax, intellij-idea, format, autoformatting

IntelliJ formats this code

```
TypeReference ref = new TypeReference<ArrayList<CrawlRequest>>() {};
```

by inserting a newline after the left curly brace

```
TypeReference ref = new TypeReference<ArrayList<CrawlRequest>>() {
};
```

Is there any way to stop it from doing this?

Comment: Did you go to File - Settings - Code Style - Java, and under Wrapping and Braces uncheck all the 'Array Initializer' new lines and wrapping?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look at the `Java` `Code Style` settings, in the `Wrapping and Braces` tab. Oddly enough, it's the `Simple classes in one line` option that controls the adding of the newline in your line of code.

[image: IntelliJ Code style settings page]